# YouTube API Inbox Request doesn't always work

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, inbox

I',m trying to get Inbox Messages for authenticated Youtube's user's profile.This is my code

```
def GetInboxMessage(self):
  uri = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/inbox?v=2&key=%s' %DEVELOPER_KEY
  print 'GET INBOX\n'
  feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)

  for entry in feed.entry:  
    try:    
        PrintVideoDetails(self,entry,'videomessage')
    except:
        pass
```

This works fine for my account. When i tried a friend's account , I get the following error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py",
>   line 183, in GetYouTubeVideoFeed
>        return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoFeedFromString) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1108,
>   in Get
>       'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
>
> gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 500, 'body': "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>GData`ServiceException`Internal
>   Error", 'reason': 'Internal Server
>   Error'}

and I don't know the way to handle it. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error better analyzes network packet or send private message to youtube team.

Reference: 1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/HzPsLiNKJuo/TgZ3NfokbdwJ
           2. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=537